# NSTimer fire specific code, not selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, alert, nstimer

I am trying to make a UIAlertView auto-dismiss after three seconds.
I know how to make an NSTimer, and how to dismiss the UIAlertView separately, but I can't figure out how to make the dismiss-alert code run directly from the NSTimer, and NOT from a method.

Here is my code (the UIAlertView is named `alert`):

The timer:

`[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(`***method***`) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];`

Dismiss the UIAlertView:

`[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];`

I can't dismiss the UIAlertView from a different method than the one that creates it (unless anyone knows of a way to that), so I need the above code to be called from **within** the first method, when the NSTimer fires.

Thanks in advance for any help / advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSTimer` only works with a selector, there is no way to directly call a method.

Use `dispatch_after` instead of a timer.

```
UIAlertView *alert = ... // create the alert view
[alert show];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:alert.cancelButtonIndex animated:YES];
});
```

If you really want to use a timer you can do:

```
UIAlertView *alert = ... // create the alert view
[alert show];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(dismissAlert:) userInfo:alert repeats:NO];
```

Then your timer method would be:

```
- (void)dismissAlert:(NSTimer *)timer {
    UIAlertView *alert = timer.userInfo;

    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:alert.cancelButtonIndex animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: +1 for using `dispatch_after()`. I created a category on NSObject that adds a method `performBlock:afterDelay:`. That way you can write code without all that dispatch_time gobbledygook that I can never remember.

Comment: @DuncanC There's nothing to remember. Type `dispatch_after` in Xcode and one of the completion options is for a full `dispatch_after` code snippet. All you have to do is change the time in seconds and fill in the block. But the category method is a nice idea.